# How to set up a proxy to route all traffic through?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, socks-proxy, http-proxy

I run Ubuntu on my home computer. Is there a simple way of setting up a proxy server on that computer? At least so that I can use it as a proxy server for HTTP, but if it isn't very difficult so that I can use it as a proxy for a whole computer so I can use for example TeamViewer, which is blocked on the network the client computer is on.

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an HTTP proxy on Ubuntu simply install Squid:

```
apt-get install squid
```

As far as I remember it works without adjusting any configuration.

But I doubt this would help you in any way resolving any restrictions placed on your network. All traffic will still go through your machine, just with another process in the middle.

Comment: Hi again! It's for the school network. If I try to go to http://www.teamviewer.com/ which is blocked on the school network the soon to be proxy on my home network will resolve that, right? Because my proxy isn't blocked.

Comment: If you want to get around limitations of your school network by using an HTTP proxy at home, yes, that could work. Although I would advise against that. First of all, your proxy would be accessible from the internet. Second of all, you shouldn't try to circumvent limitations placed on your network by a higher authority.

Comment: I asked them why they had blocked TeamViewer, and they said that they hadn't done it. It was their bosses who had done it, and told me to try to get around it. xD

Comment: Maybe you'll want to look into setting up a VPN (like OpenVPN) then. There are many guides online explaining how to do it.

Comment: I tried VPN once, but it seems it doesn't work with our ISP..